# TypeError: val.replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, methods, foreach

Here is my code, I want to *replace vowels* in a string with the *index values* but when I was running the code I'm getting an error called "TypeError: val.replaceAll is not a function".

I also used **replace()** method(got 2 l3v1 j0vasscript) in place of **replaceAll()** method but I didn't get the desired output.

```
let val = "I love JavasScript";
val = val.toLowerCase();
let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

vowels.forEach((letter, index) => {
    val = val.replace(letter, index);
});
console.log(val);
```

Comment: It works for me, can you show the expected output please ?

Comment: `replaceAll` has been around for a couple of years... the main browser that [doesn't support it is IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll), which is now dead anyway... so unless you're working with legacy browsers, it should work

Comment: @iDziDz The expected output is 2 l3v1 j0v0sscr2pt.

Comment: That's what i get ;)

Comment: `replace` with a string argument only replaces one occurence.

Comment: Ok, Is it work on Visual Studio Code? Actually, I'm executing it on vs code.

Comment: VS Code ? You need a web browser to exec it. I worked for me in a chrome dev tool

Comment: @iDziDz It worked on the Web browser.